# Set maximumBillingTier when reading from BigQuery in Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running GCP Dataflow job when I'm reading data from BigQuery as a query result. I'm using google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all version 1.9.0. The code fragment that sets up the pipeline looks like this:

```
PCollection<TableRow> myRows = pipeline.apply(BigQueryIO.Read
            .fromQuery(query)
            .usingStandardSql()
            .withoutResultFlattening()
            .named("Input " + tableId)
    );
```

The query is quite complex what results in error message:

> Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 8 or higher required., error: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 8 or higher required.

I'd like to set `maximumBillingTier` as it is done in Web UI or in bq script. I can't find any way to do so except for setting default for the entire project which is unfortunately not an option.

I tried to set it through these without success:

- DataflowPipelineOptions - neither this nor any interface it extends seems to have that setting
- BigQueryIO.Read.Bound - I would expect it to be there just next to `usingStandardSql` and others similar but obviously it is not there
- JobConfigurationQuery - this class has all cool settings but it seems it is not used at all when setting up a pipeline

Is there any way to pass this setting from within Dataflow job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a Googler will correct me, but it looks like you are right. I can't see this parameter exposed either. I checked both the [Dataflow](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK) and the [Beam](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java) APIs.

Under the hood, Dataflow is using `JobConfigurationQuery` from the BigQuery API, but it simply doesn't expose that parameter through its own API.

One workaround I see is to first run your complex query using the BigQuery API directly - before dropping into your pipeline. That way you can set the max billing tier through the `JobConfigurationQuery` class. Write the results of that query to another table in BigQuery.

Then finally, in your pipeline, just read in the table which was created from the complex query.

Comment: Thanks! This is the exact approach we have chosen as a workaround.

Comment: Great! In that case, can you upvote/accept my answer please @TomazLecki. That's how Stack Overflow works ;-)

Comment: I got it upvoted already but as I do not have enough reputation the vote is noted yet it is not visible for others (I hope I understood that right). I want to give it a little bit more time but if I get no answer from google or someone else with any better solution then I will mark your answer as accepted as it seems to be the best workaround - easy and without additional costs.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense.