# I'm getting a "Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 3 or higher required" error message from my Dataflow job

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

My Dataflow job that queries data from BigQuery is failing with an error:

```
Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 3 or higher required.
```

The same Dataflow job worked with another project of mine and I'm unable to determine how I set the tier in the Dataflow API.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the BigQueryIO library included in the open source Dataflow SDKs do not have an option for setting the maximumBillingTier option. The reason your Dataflow job worked in another project is likely due to the default maximumBillingTier set for that project meeting the requirement of your query. You can find more information about BigQuery pricing and specifically maximumBillingTier here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute

There are a couple potential workarounds. The first is to set the default maximumBillingTier for the project to the level required by Dataflow. It should be noted that this will affect all queries and not just those submitted by Dataflow. This can be done by filling out the form found here:

https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/bigquery_high_compute_queries_quota_request_form

Another option is to run your query using the BigQuery API directly, in which you can set this value. You then could save the results as a new table which could be read in by your Dataflow job. This is the suggestion from another post on the topic here:

[Set maximumBillingTier when reading from BigQuery in Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957476/set-maximumbillingtier-when-reading-from-bigquery-in-dataflow)

The BigQuery and Dataflow teams are working on providing this option natively in Dataflow SDKs.